# How do i split a continuous string that is made up of two different word that are separated with "|" where i have to print just the first word?

Tags: python

So I am doing a task where I need to read a line from a text file which goes like this: "Name|Something" and I have to print "Username: Name" and "Password: Something". Here is what I came up with but I don't really know how to use the split command in this instance:

```
def main():
infile = open("users","r")
    print("Username: ",e[0] for e in infile.split("|"))
    print("Password: ",e[1] for e in infile.split("|"))
main()
```

Comment: `infile` is not a string: it is a file object. You'll have to read from `infile` first (or iterate over it).

Comment: IE, save the contents of `infile` with `contents = infile.read().split('|')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `str.split()` once per input line, perhaps in a loop.

For example:

```
with open("users") as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        username, password = line.split('|')
        print("Username:", username.strip())
        print("Password:", password.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over the lines for example

```
with open('users', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        username, password = line.split('|')
        print('Username: {}'.format(username))
        print('Password: {}'.format(password))
```